# Efficiently adding numpy arrays with duplicate destination indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have two numpy arrays, `A` and `B`, which are potentially very large.  I'd like to find a way to *efficiently* add values to certain entries in `A` by specifying the indices at which each entry of `B` should be added.

Normally, one could use the following syntax:

`A[indices] += B`

The problem is that this doesn't behave as I would expect in cases where `indices` contains *duplicate values*.  The only solution I've found is to use a manual for-loop, but I was hoping there might be a more efficient way.  For example:

```
A = np.array([100, 200, 300, 400])
B = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
indices = [1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1]

for i, index in enumerate(indices):
    A[index] += B[i]
```

This yields `A = [103, 212, 306, 400]`, as desired.

In contrast, `A[indices] += B` yields `A = [103, 206, 304, 400]`, which suggests that the operations `A[1] += 1`, `A[1] += 5`, `A[2] += 2` are being omitted.

Note: I view the desired behavior as being somewhat similar to a "group by" operation in SQL -- for each value of `k`, I want to group all entries of `B` where `indices == k` and add them into the `k`th position of `A`.

My question is: **is there a more efficient way to perform this operation?**  I'm hoping there's some built-in numpy functionality which would be better-optimized for performance than my for-loop above.

For reference, I'm using numpy version 1.13.3.

#### Higher-dimensional case

If it's possible to generalize this to higher-dimensional arrays, I'd be interested to hear that, too.  For example, is there a more efficient way to perform the following?

```
A = (1 + np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)) * 100
B = (1 + np.arange(18)).reshape(3,6)
row_indices = [2, 0, 2]
col_indices = [1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1]

for i, row_index in enumerate(row_indices):
    for j, col_index in enumerate(col_indices):
        A[row_index, col_index] += B[i, j]
```

Comment: `np.add.at` is what you're looking for

Comment: That higher dim case looks wrong. Shouldn't it be : `for j, col_index in enumerate(col_indices.ravel()):`? Did you run it at your end?

Comment: @Divakar -- oops, the higher-dim snippet was incorrect.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I've edited it and confirmed that it now works as intended.

Comment: For completeness, the solution for the 1d case is: `np.add.at(A, indices, B)`, and the solution for the 2d case is `np.add.at(A, (np.atleast_2d(row_indices).transpose(), np.atleast_2d(col_indices)), B)`